# find the components

Tags: c, controls

all. I'm making a easy function that can find the components of an integer

for example, if I input 4 6 4 3 2 2 1 1 ,

means i have to find the components of the number '4' (1st) from

the followed 6 (2nd) elements 4,3,2,2,1,1

so the expected output is like
4
3+1
2+2
2+1+1

and when you can't find any of the componets,  print NONE.

My function is like :

```
int Addition(int command[], int target, int length ){
/* command : the input line
   length : the amount of elements need to be checked */ 

    int i = 0, j = 1, k = 0;
    int sum = command[0];
    int content[length];

    content[0] = command[0];

    while(j <= length){
        if(sum == target){
            for(i = 0; i < k; ++i){
                printf("%d+", content[i]);
            }
            printf("%d\n", content[i]);
            sum = command[0];
            k = 0;
            ++counter;
        }
        sum += command[j];

        if(sum > target){
            sum -= command[j];
        }else{
            ++k;
            content[k] = command[j];
        }
        ++j;
    }
    if( length == 0 && counter == 0 )
        printf("NONE\n");
    else{
        return Addition(command+1, target, length-1);
    }
}
```

my problem is that i don't know how to set up the condition

to print NONE when there's no components ,and I can't avoid

printing the same answer. My output is like :

Sums of 4:
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
3+1
3+1
2+2
2+1+1
2+1+1
NONE

sorry for the long description, but can someone give me some hint to my problems ??

thank you!

Comment: Hi ,all. The problem is a little bit difficult than i thought. Try the test data : 50 6 30 25 20 15 10 5 . And the correct output should be like :30+20
30+15+5
25+20+5
25+15+10
20+15+10+5

Comment: hi, guys. This problem is so difficult for me. I think the code i wrote was totally wrong after a tricky test data 10 12 10 9 8 6 5 4 4 3 2 2 1 1. Can someone give me more hints?? Recursion problems always disturb me.

Answer (score 1):

Split the program into two phases. The first phase only finds solutions and doesn't print them; instead it stashes them in some way (I can think of at least three). The second phase removes duplicates and then prints the de-duped list, or `NONE` if there were none.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a recursive function, you should be placing a test to make sure that `length != 0` right at the start of the function so that you don't cycle through an entire loop, accessing memory that shouldn't be accessed (because at that point `command` is pointing to the end of the memory segment, and you would have done operations like assigning the value of `sum` from the value of what `command` is pointing to).

Secondly, I don't see anywhere why your function needs to have a return type of `int`.  It seems that `void` will work perfectly well, as you're not returning anything from the function (i.e., if you're at the end you simply are printing "NONE" and returning without any return value, so there is no need for the return-type to be `int` ... it should be `void`).

So, since you're returning nothing (i.e, `void`), the first line in your function before you do anything else should look something like:

```
if (length == 0)
{
    printf("NONE\n");
    return;
}
```

That way you catch where you need to stop the recursive calls. Then the last line of your function can be (you can omit the "return" before the recursive function call since you're returning `void`):

```
Addition(command+1, target, length-1);
```

Finally, I believe you're printing all these repeat values because you're incrementing through your `command` array incorrectly (it seems overly complex).  You should simply need a single for-loop or while-loop where you match the first variable in `command` against the rest of the values and check if their sums equal the target.

I've [made a working copy of your function over at ideone](http://ideone.com/ejhWe), so you can check out what I'm talking about, especially the simplification of the loop.

Hope this helps,

Jason

Comment: Thanks!Jason. Your hint works. It does help me solve the problem of repeating printing the components. Thanks! But sorry for I didn't correctly describe my another problem. The expected output of test data "4 6 4 3 2 2 1 1" is 4
3+1
2+2
2+1+1
(with no NONE)

Comment: The NONE shows up only if there's not even one way to seperate the target.For example if the test data is 10 3 2 1 1. then NONE is print. 
by the way , I'm totally new to programming. So I think the site you put your code is so cool! Thank you !!

Comment: I would just then have some type of global flag that you trigger if you get at least one match ... if there are no matches, then the flag is not triggered, and after all the recursive calls complete, you can then print "NONE" if there were no matches.  Here is modified code for that: http://ideone.com/wFxPd

Comment: Jason, try this test data.10 12 10 9 8 6 5 4 4 3 2 2 1 1. It's so tricky !

Comment: Yes, it's tricky, but by making a dynamic data-structure (in this case a linked-list does the trick) to store your solutions, you can filter out any repeats that will occur because of having to run through the list multiple times looking for all the possible solutions.  So the basic workflow is to fill the list recursively, and then print the list once the recursive process is complete. Here is a new example of how that would work, along with a couple of different samples: http://ideone.com/gCVtk ... To be honest though, you don't need recursion for this -- a loop would do just fine.

Comment: In other words, you can't simply find the first solution and bail ... you have to check through the entire list.  But that will create repeating solutions, i.e., "10 9+1 9+1 9+1 9+1 9+1 ... 8+2 8+2 ...".  By having a dynamic data-structure (as Scott mentions in his post), you can filter out the repeats.  There are a couple different ways we could recursively traverse the list, but still in the end, you're going to end up with repeats because of the data you're inputting, and therefore you will need a way to filter out those repeats.

Comment: Sorry, had to fix a bug where if `first_var == target`, we simply printed to the output rather than trying to add that solution to the list.  Here's the fix: http://ideone.com/ztxtJ

Comment: For curiosity's sake, here is another version of the solution, this time using a more "recursive" algorithm ... I say "more recursive" because there is a deferred operation taking place rather than something that the tail-recursive calls of the former example which basically amount to loops algorithmically.  The bad news though is this solution has a running time of O(N!), meaning it searches through all the permutations, and there are N! permutations. So if you double the size of N, you have 2N*(N-1)*...*(N+1), making the computation quite expensive. Here is the link: http://ideone.com/ePQX5

Comment: Hmm, the version at http://ideone.com/ztxt has a fundamental flaw where it's not checking all the possibilities.  While it passes a couple of the tests, it failed the `10 12 10 ...` list. There's going to have to be some way to check for values that have already been visited in order to make the search more robust, especially for repeating values.  The recursive version at http://ideone.com/vY0Xe gives the correct results since it checks all possible permutations.  Here are the results: `8+1+1 6+2+1+1 5+3+1+1 4+4+1+1 4+2+2+1+1 9+1 6+3+1 5+4+1 5+2+2+1 4+3+2+1 6+2+2 8+2 5+3+2 4+4+2 6+4 10`

Comment: Hi,Jason. I've finally finished the problem, and it's also a recursion version. Here is my code, http://ideone.com/URYBi

Comment: Nice clean solution :) ... BTW, I also discovered looking at your code the simple fix that was messing up my earlier example and missing a solution on your "trickier" input: http://ideone.com/QQuTH ... of course it's not a clean as yours, but I hope I was able to help you out! :)

Comment: I'm sure you did! Jason. Your code inspires me a lot.               Thank you!

Comment: BTW, and input of `10 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1` gave me the answer `NONE` with the current solution ... I'm guessing it's tripping up on the code where you skip past any repeating values in the `while` loop on lines 44-45.  I would have normally expected an output like `2+2+2+1+1+1+1 2+2+2+2+1+1 2+2+2+2+2`

Comment: Okay, I found the problem ... you're initializing the first call to `Addition` incorrectly.  It should be something like `Addition(command+1, tempArray, command[0], initial_length, counter, sum)`, where `initial_length` is the number of characters in the command array.

Comment: BTW, one last thought to make your algorithm more robust, is you should make sure you input a sorted array ... I've noticed that the current algorithm outputs repeat results (i.e., the while-loop on lines 44-45 stops working) if the array is not sorted (i.e., try `10 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3`).